# Get image name out of image address with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the image name out of the address.

This is the value I with the JavaScript:

```
http://localhost:51557/img/column-sortable.png

document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_iSortColumn").value = columnNumber;
            alert(imageName);
```

Whats the best way to get column-sortable.png out of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there's never anything after the image name in the URL (no query string or hash) then the following should work:

```
var str = "http://localhost:51557/img/column-sortable.png";
alert(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function:

```
var url = http://localhost:51557/img/column-sortable.png;
var elementArray = url.split('/');
var imageName = elementArray[elementArray.length - 1];
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqLpV/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try using Regex, check this out.

```
var imgURL = "http://localhost:51557/img/column-sortable.png";
var imageName = imgURL.replace( /^.*?([^/]+\..+?)$/, '$1' );
alert(imageName);
```